# combining/merging multiple 2d arrays into single array by using python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, gdal

I have four 2 dimensional np arrays. Shape of each array is (203 , 135). Now I want join all these arrays into one single array with respect to latitude and longitude.

I have used code below to read data

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import os
import glob
from pyhdf import SD
import datetime
import mpl_toolkits.basemap.pyproj as pyproj

DATA = ({})
files = glob.glob('MOD04*')
files.sort()
for n, f in enumerate(files):       
    SDS_NAME='Deep_Blue_Aerosol_Optical_Depth_550_Land'
    hdf=SD.SD(f)
    lat = hdf.select('Latitude')
    latitude = lat[:]
    min_lat=latitude.min()
    max_lat=latitude.max()
    lon = hdf.select('Longitude')
    longitude = lon[:]
    min_lon=longitude.min()
    max_lon=longitude.max()
    sds=hdf.select(SDS_NAME)
    data=sds.get()

    p = pyproj.Proj(proj='utm', zone=45, ellps='WGS84')
    x,y = p(longitude, latitude)

    def set_element(elements, x, y, data):
        # Set element with two coordinates.
        elements[x + (y * 10)] = data

    elements = []
    set_element(elements,x,y,data)
```

But I got error: only integer arrays with one element can be converted to an index

you can find the data: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B2rkXkOkG7ExMElPRDd5YkNEeDQ

I have created toy datasets for this problem as per requested. 
what I want is to get one single array from four (a,b,c,d) arrays. whose dimension should be something like (406, 270)

```
a = (np.random.rand(27405)).reshape(203,135)
b = (np.random.rand(27405)).reshape(203,135)
c = (np.random.rand(27405)).reshape(203,135)
d = (np.random.rand(27405)).reshape(203,135)
a_x = (np.random.uniform(10,145,27405)).reshape(203,135)
a_y = (np.random.uniform(204,407,27405)).reshape(203,135)
d_x = (np.random.uniform(150,280,27405)).reshape(203,135)
d_y = (np.random.uniform(204,407,27405)).reshape(203,135)
b_x = (np.random.uniform(150,280,27405)).reshape(203,135)
b_y = (np.random.uniform(0,202,27405)).reshape(203,135)
c_x = (np.random.uniform(10,145,27405)).reshape(203,135)
c_y = (np.random.uniform(0,202,27405)).reshape(203,135)
```

any help?

Comment: please define toy data input (instead of posting a link) and define the output you wish to achieve for this toy data example.

Comment: also, in your for loop, you repeatedly set elements = [], effectively erasing the previous results, which you achieve by set_elements

Comment: @NikolasRieble, Okey I will create toy data and post it for you

Comment: And what do you mean by "join these arrays into one single array"? Do you want the mean/max/min/sum/etc?

Comment: @ irenemeanspeace actually these arrays are spatial datasets. they have different latitude and longitude (i.e. different data position). So I am trying to make one single array from four different arrays.

Comment: @NikolasRieble I have created toy data sets and placed on edited version where, a_x, and a_y represent the respective longitude and latitude of array a

Answer (score 0):

This should be a comment, yet the comment space is not enough for these questions. Therefore I am posting here:

You say that you have 4 input arrays (a,b,c,d) which are somehow to be intergrated into an output array. As far as is understood, two of these arrays contain positional information (x,y) such as longitude and latitude. The only line in your code, where you combine several input arrays is here:

```
def set_element(elements, x, y, data):
        # Set element with two coordinates.
        elements[x + (y * 10)] = data
```

Here you have four input variables (elements, x, y, data) which I assume to be your input arrays (a,b,c,d). In this operation yet you do not combine them, but you overwrite an element of elements (index: x + 10y) with a new value (data).

Therefore, I do not understand your target output.

When I was asking for toy data, I had something like this in mind:

```
a = [[1,2]]
b = [[3,4]]
c = [[5,6]]
d = [[7,8]]
```

This would be such an easy example that you  could easily say:

What I want is this:

```
res = [[[1,2],[3,4]],[[5,6],[7,8]]]
```

Then we could help you to find an answer.

Please, thus, provide more information about the operation that you want to conduct either mathematically notated ( such as x = a +b*c +d) or with toy data so that we can deduce the function you ask for.

Comment: Thank you for correcting me and making my question clear..now I understand something going wrong in define statement...okey I will try